# Generating classes from multiple wsdl files using maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: maven, wsdl, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I can generate classes from one wsdl file like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
            <include>bwl_1_1.wsdl</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <generatePackage>bwl.wsdl</generatePackage>
        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/bwl</generateDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I try using multiple `<plugin>`, just one of them is generated. I found that if I want to generate classes from multiple files, I should use `<executions>`. However when I wrap `<configuration>` into `<executions>`, it no longer generates, in fact it generates something from xsd file in the directory...

My not working attempt:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.3</version>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>bwl</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>bwl_1_1.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                    <generatePackage>bwl.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/bwl</generateDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>score</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>score_1_1.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                    <generatePackage>score.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/score</generateDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>

    </plugin>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Add `${basedir}` in front of the path in `<schemaDirectory>` tag as follows

> `<schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>`

Then it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Use ${basedir} (inside generateDirectory and schemaDirectory) and forceRegenerate flag. Working example below:

```
<execution>
    <id>MyService</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <generatePackage>pl.generated.wsdl</generatePackage>
        <generateDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</generateDirectory>
        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
        <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
        <schemaIncludes>
            <include>
                myService.wsdl
            </include>
        </schemaIncludes>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```